# How to remove the cookie and check the status of the cookie in the same request in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I want to remove the cookie, but there is the following method that gets called. The method checks whether the cookie exists or not and executes the code based on that. So basically, if the cookie doesn't exist, the method should do nothing. This is all happening in the same request.

### Code to remove the cookie

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
cookie.Value = "";
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookie.Add(cookie);
```

After the execution of the above code snippet, if I try to access the cookie in the same request using the below code, it still exists and gives me the previous value.

### Code to check if the cookie exists

```
if(Request.Cookies["test"] != null) {
    var value = Request.Cookie["test"].Value;
}
```

All this works in the subsequent requests but not for the same request.

After I remove the cookie, if I try to access the same cookie anywhere in the code for the same request, it should return null or should not exist.

How can I achieve this?

I tried another solution, like setting the cookie name to null, but it didn't work.

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are changing cookie in the Response. It won't be impacted in same Request. You can not achieve. Can you explain the use case which is leading you use this approach?

Comment: In general you can think about the request as a **readonly** structure, you should not bend it. The data which is inside that can be considered as facts. Facts should not change over time. On the other hand you have full control over the response and you can think of that as a **writeonly** strucutre.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya There is a business logic class that handles calls to the services and brings data at the same time sets the session and cookie for the bits and pieces of data. The business logic class methods are called before any other operations. On the code-behind page, I am reading/updating/deleting the cookie/session in order to handle the user interaction and update the UI accordingly. Anyways, I got it working by executing the below code but not sure if that's the ideal solution.

`HttpContext.Current.Requst.Cookies.Remove("test");`